# Pictureboxes not becoming visible

Tags: c#, picturebox, sender

Sorry, but I have another problem. In my code I can now get it to randomly assign pictures to pictureboxes but unfortunately I cannot get any of the pictureboxes to become visible, upon clicking them, this event should happen:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The timer is only on after two non-matching  
        // icons have been shown to the player,  
        // so ignore any clicks if the timer is running 
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
        {
            return;
        }


        PictureBox clickedpicturebox = sender as PictureBox;

        if (clickedpicturebox == null)
        {
            // If the clicked picture is visible, the player clicked 
            // an icon that's already been revealed -- 
            // ignore the click 
            if (clickedpicturebox.Visible == true)
                return;

            // If firstClicked is null, this is the first icon 
            // in the pair that the player clicked,  
            // so set firstClicked to the picturebox that the player  
            // clicked, make it visible, and return 
            if (firstClicked.Tag == null)
            {
                clickedpicturebox = firstClicked;
                firstClicked.Tag = clickedpicturebox.Tag;
                firstClicked.Visible = true;

            }

            // If the player gets this far, the timer isn't 
            // running and firstClicked isn't null, 
            // so this must be the second icon the player clicked 
            // Set its property to visible
            clickedpicturebox = secondClicked;
            secondClicked.Tag = clickedpicturebox.Tag;
            secondClicked.Visible = true;

            // If the player gets this far, the player  
            // clicked two different icons, so start the  
            // timer (which will wait three quarters of  
            // a second, and then hide the icons)
            timer1.Start();
        }

    }
```

But for some reason, even if I strip it down to just a line that says:

PictureBox clickedpicturebox = sender as PictureBox;
clickedpicturebox.Visible = true;

It still doesn't work, could it be because I selected multiple pictures to apply the event to at the same time?

Also, incase you need it, I have the properties of the first picturebox here, all other pictureboxes are essentially the same.

```
// 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 119);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
```

EDIT: I would like to thank everyone, the problem is now resolved, I have used the labels allow me to easily interact between the foreground and background colours, allowing for easy transition between a label and a picturebox.

Comment: Could you provide a complete verifiable runnable example? P.S.: Don't excuse yourself, I don't know you.

Comment: does `pictureBox1_Click` run at all? `pictureBox1.Visible = false;` i don't think it can be clicked

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, it's just blank, there is literally nothing to be seen or done if this code is in place, which is why I am so confused, without it all the pictures are there if I set their visible property to be enabled.

Comment: So, what property should I put in @ASh if I want to be able to not see the picture and still click it? Should I play around with colours?

Comment: check the following in addition to the comment of ASh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427820/winforms-button-does-visible-false-imply-enabled-false

Comment: basically the user can only interact with things that he can see. You can still click on the underlying form (or whatever control is shown instead of the picturebox) and compare the click position with the boundaries/position of your images. You can then fire `pictureBox1_Click` from within the `Form1_Click` event if the position matches.

Answer (score 0):

H W and ASh are both correct, the problem is resolved.